# Apache2 Subdomain not working

Tags: ubuntu, vps, apache2, subdomain, webmin

I'm trying to get a subdomain to work but, it is just straight up not working. I have it registered in everywhere, and running `apachectl -S`, the subdomain pops up but it just shows my main domain. This is my code in the 000-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =prodigyhacking.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName thefaqman.prodigyhacking.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/thefaqman.prodigyhacking.com
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Did I do something wrong? The files that need to be in the folder ate there, and it was working earlier. It was working until I had to reinstall apache because it started breaking it's modules. After that, it just stopped wanting to use my subdomains. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a OpenVZ VPS with Webmin (if that's helpful). Apache is up to date.

Comment: Did you run the command a2ensite?

Comment: Yes, I did. It said that the subdomain wasn't a website.

Comment: Can you add the output from $ apache2ctl -S   I am confused when you say " running apachectl -S, the subdomain pops up but it just shows my main domain"                  Also, can you post the output from your a2ensite command?